# Couchbase: 20k items stuck in Tap Queue

Tags: memcached, couchbase

We are currently evaluating couchbase as a memcached replacement in the first place. Our setup looks like this:

php -> localhost moxi -> couchbase bucket (Total bucket size = 10240 MB (2048 MB x 5 nodes with replica count 1))
The Servers have 16GB RAM and are SSD backed.

We were inserting at about 400 ops/s and had no problem for a few days. When we reached about 13 million items. We found out that we forgot to implement the delete function in our testsetup and a lot of keys had no expiration set.

To start over again we flushed the bucket through the webinterface. This where our problems began.
We started to see that we had temp ooms, back-offs, and tap queue was filled with 20k items. the drain and fill rate was nearly the same. See attached screenshot
[image: Total TAP queue items]
What also catched our eye was that node 4 had only 220k items, where everyone else had around 1.39M
[image: Node overview]
Somehow it looks like the replication messed up something, but im relatively new to couchbase. Any hints, suggestions? - See more at: http://www.couchbase.com/communities/q-and-a/20k-items-stuck-tap-queue#sthash.v9MxNnTk.dpuf

The problem was solved for a short time, after removing the failing node from the cluster.
So now with this four nodes left in the cluster, after some hours the same happend again with another node. We tried setting the now failing node into FailOver state. That fixed the problem again, but after Re-Adding the node, the same phenomenon happened again on that node.

Other things we realized are:
* Three out of four nodes have thousands of items in their TAP replication queue, but one 
("the failing one") has 0.
* Also three out of four nodes have a back-off rate of around 400, but one ("the failing one") has 0.
* Only the failing one has a massive amount of "Temp OOMs per second", but the other three have 0.

The phenomenon seems to disappear, if we lower the load to the servers by disabling the couchbase-writes for one out of two software project writing to couchbase.
But if we enable the writes again, after around 10 minutes we can see this in the memcached.log on the failing node:

```
Tue Dec 17 12:29:05.010547 CET 3: (CENSORED) Received error[86] from mccouch for unknown
Tue Dec 17 12:29:05.010576 CET 3: (CENSORED) Retry notify CouchDB of update, vbucket=277 rev=522
Tue Dec 17 12:29:08.748103 CET 3: (CENSORED) Received error[86] from mccouch for unknown
Tue Dec 17 12:29:08.748257 CET 3: (CENSORED) Retry notify CouchDB of update, vbucket=321 rev=948
Tue Dec 17 12:40:17.354448 CET 3: (CENSORED) Received error[86] from mccouch for unknown
Tue Dec 17 12:40:17.354476 CET 3: (CENSORED) Retry notify CouchDB of update, vbucket=303 rev=491
```

This error then happens around 5 times within four hours:
`Tue Dec 17 14:19:32.145071 CET 3: (CENSORED) TAP (Producer) eq_tapq:replication_ns_1@10.65.20.12 - Suspend for 5.00 secs`
And after these four hours it starts spamming this instantly (Maybe, because the load increased heavily, because in the evening our page generates much more load than in the morning/noon) together with this "error from mccouch":

```
Tue Dec 17 16:42:30.875343 CET 3: (CENSORED) TAP (Producer) eq_tapq:replication_ns_1@10.65.20.12 - Suspend for 5.00 secs
Tue Dec 17 16:42:36.493317 CET 3: (CENSORED) TAP (Producer) eq_tapq:replication_ns_1@10.65.20.12 - Suspend for 5.00 secs
Tue Dec 17 16:43:25.239876 CET 3: (CENSORED) Received error[86] from mccouch for unknown
Tue Dec 17 16:43:25.240052 CET 3: (CENSORED) Retry notify CouchDB of update, vbucket=296 rev=483
Tue Dec 17 16:43:25.903997 CET 3: (CENSORED) TAP (Producer) eq_tapq:replication_ns_1@10.65.20.12 - Suspend for 5.00 secs
Tue Dec 17 16:43:31.906178 CET 3: (CENSORED) TAP (Producer) eq_tapq:replication_ns_1@10.65.20.12 - Suspend for 5.00 secs
Tue Dec 17 16:43:36.913045 CET 3: (CENSORED) TAP (Producer) eq_tapq:replication_ns_1@10.65.20.12 - Suspend for 5.00 secs
Tue Dec 17 16:43:42.919114 CET 3: (CENSORED) TAP (Producer) eq_tapq:replication_ns_1@10.65.20.12 - Suspend for 5.00 secs
Tue Dec 17 16:43:48.920354 CET 3: (CENSORED) TAP (Producer) eq_tapq:replication_ns_1@10.65.20.12 - Suspend for 5.00 secs
Tue Dec 17 16:43:54.924017 CET 3: (CENSORED) TAP (Producer) eq_tapq:replication_ns_1@10.65.20.12 - Suspend for 5.00 secs
Tue Dec 17 16:44:00.928572 CET 3: (CENSORED) TAP (Producer) eq_tapq:replication_ns_1@10.65.20.12 - Suspend for 5.00 secs
```

We have no clue what is happening here, why this failing node seems to reject every replication and throwing this error.
Do you have any idea?

Thanks for all your help and greetings from Cologne,

Andy!

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you just want to delete all items in the Bucket have you tried just deleting and re-creating the bucket?

This will be *much* faster than flush, as flush actually needs to send a delete request for *every* document in the bucket.

I can't find it in the docs at the moment, but I think Flush is not really recommended with the latest versions.

Answer (score 0):

you are not writing what is your operating system. If it's Linux try to check maximum amount of open sockets for user running the Couchbase. Check the file /etc/security/limits.conf.

the command for check on Linux is: ulimit -Hn.

Hope that helps.

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try these settings:

http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.1/#specifying-backoff-for-replication